# In MongoDB, is there a performance penalty for testing that a field is null or unset, versus testing against a specific value?

Tags: mongodb

In MongoDB, which of the following alternatives is more efficient (in terms of processing speed)?

1. Use a single field to indicate *both* whether a document has a certain property, and the value of that property. This implies that queries to find documents having the property would need to be similar to `{'someField' : {$ne : null}}`. The field is assumed to exist on all documents.
2. Use two separate fields, one a Boolean to indicate whether a document has the property at all (say, `'has_someFieldProperty'`), and another field to hold the actual value (`'someField'` as above). This implies that queries to find documents having the property could be of the form `{'has_someFieldProperty': true}`.

Context: I have a 25,000,000 document database and currently use approach #2. I'd like to reduce the size of the database. The representation currently has this obvious redundancy, and so one option is to convert it to use approach #1. But I don't have enough experience with MongoDB to know whether testing against non-null is slower or more intensive on the server side than simply testing against a Boolean value.

**UPDATE #1**: In the comments to this question, it was pointed out that #1 could also be achieved by testing against the field data type, for example using `{'someField': {'$type': 2} }`. This is true; however, my question is really more about the performance tradeoffs of different approaches rather than *how* to find or filter documents.  I changed the wording of the question to try to make the emphasis more clear.

Comment: What do you mean by *null value*? Does it mean the field is absent or the field is present but value equals `null`?

Comment: Oops, sorry for the lack of clarity. I mean the field is present, but null in value. (More specifically, using pymongo, the value of `None`.) I will update the question to clarify this.

Comment: Is the field's value type for those documents where the field is not `null` the same?

Comment: *"Is the field's value type for those documents where the field is not null the same?"*: yes. They are all strings.

Comment: Well in that case simply use one field and filter your documents using the [`$type`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/type/) operator.  `{'someField': {'$type': 2} }`.

Comment: @user3100115 That is very clever :-). Thanks.